# Creating an empty TEMPORARY table taking more than 10 seconds

Tags: mysql, temp-tables, query-performance

I am trying to create a temporary table on one of my servers installed with mysql 5.5.27. To my surprise, it is taking 12 seconds.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEST (name VARCHAR(10)) ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (12.02 sec)
```

Shall someone explain what is going wrong here ?

Here is the profiling information:

```
+----------------------+-----------+
| Status               | Duration  |
+----------------------+-----------+
| starting             |  0.000094 |
| checking permissions |  0.000007 |
| Opening tables       |  0.000009 |
| System lock          |  0.000031 |
| creating table       | 12.011561 |
| After create         |  0.000022 |
| query end            |  0.000004 |
| osing tables         |  0.000003 |
| freeing items        |  0.000022 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000007 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000059 |
| cleaning up          |  0.000003 |
+----------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: 64 MB is the limit on in memory temp tables. 
Memory wise there is no problem on the server.
Server is idle too...

Comment: Does this happen consistently, and what is your average time?

Comment: @scrowler: Yes, This is constantly happening and the average time is 12 seconds.

Comment: What engine are you using?

Comment: What's your `tmpdir` and what kind of filesystem is it/are they on?

Comment: @bishop: tmpdir is "/opt/mysql/tmp/instance-name/" and it has a soft link to another directory and it is having 900MB free space. might be this could be issue.

Comment: Just confirming that `/opt/mysql` is not a NFS mount or other network or removable media point?

Comment: Can you post `SHOW PROFILE ALL` and is there any change if you switch [`innodb_file_per_table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) (eg, enable if currently disabled, or vice versa)?

Comment: it's a vm filesystem. There is no additional profile information i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the load average of your server?
if you have access to the shell you can use uptime command.

$uptime

12:50:10 up 310 days, 21:15, 45 users, **load average: 0.50, 0.25, 0.10**

Maybe the problem is not on your MySQL

This post can help you to understand the load Average.
http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages

You can use the top command from the shell and SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST from MySQL to search what process are runing on your MySQL Server.
Hope this help.